# How to implement star-rating system for each product

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have a problem with star rating system. This system does not work properly for each product in my shopApp. At this moment, I figured out how to set it up only for one product. In case, when it is used for another div, the effect is seen for the first div, but not for this particular. I have no idea how to set it up in order to work for every. #HELP

I have been working on it so much time. I tried to use: 
-for loop in eventListener so that it works for each star
- parent.Node
- child.Nodes
- forEach()

```html
<div class="stars">
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="3"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="4"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="5"></a>
</div>
<div class="stars">
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="3"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="4"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="5"></a>
</div>
<div class="stars">
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="3"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="4"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="5"></a>
</div>
<div class="stars">
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="3"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="4"></a>
  <a href="#" class="star" data-star="5"></a>
</div>
```

```js
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
let rating = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('.stars').forEach(productRating => {
  productRating.querySelectorAll('.star').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (!e.target.matches('.star')) return;
      e.preventDefault();

      const starID = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-star'));

      removeClassFromElements('is-active', stars);
      highlightStars(starID);

      rating = starID;
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      if (!e.target.matches('.star')) return;

      removeClassFromElements('is-active', stars);
      const starID = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-star'));
      highlightStars(starID);
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
      removeClassFromElements('is-active', stars);
      if (rating === 0) return;
      highlightStars(rating);
    });
  });
});

function highlightStars (starID) {
  for (let i = 0; i < starID; i++) {
    stars[i].classList.add('is-active');
  }
}

function removeClassFromElements (className, elements) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove(className);
  }
}
```

I would like to have the star rating system for each div separately.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y9ouvxas/  Keep in mind, it's also possible to implement star ratings without javascript at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `highlightStars(starID)` does not contain which product was clicked, so the function will not be able to assign the correct amount of active stars.

You could use `parentElement` to get the div and then on that div loop through all children to apply the `is-active`.

Currently `highlightStars` references a `stars` variable that does not exist, so you will have to think about what each function has access to.

Comment: Oh sorry, i've forgot to add this var here, but in my code it was there. When it comes to parentElement or parentNode I've tried so many times to use it but actually I do not know how and where I should implement this. 


What would you recommend me to do in this case? 
Thanks in advance!